# How can I uninstall call recorder for Skype?

Tags: skype, uninstall

How can I uninstall call recorder for Skype? I had my OS reinstalled last week, and I found that call recorder for Skype was installed along with other programs by the technician. I don't need a call recorder for Skype and I want to uninstall it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

From the [Call Recorder FAQ](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/callrecorder/faq.html):

> Q: How do I uninstall Call Recorder?
>
> A: To uninstall Call Recorder, run the "Install Call Recorder" program
>   included in the disk image. Click "Uninstall".

The instructions indicate you should be able to run the installer, and within the process choose to uninstall.