# How can I uninstall Call Recorder for Skype if I don't know the location of the uninstaller?

Tags: macos, skype, uninstall

Someone has already asked this: [How can I uninstall call recorder for Skype?](https://superuser.com/questions/310390/how-can-i-uninstall-call-recorder-for-skype) and the answer is to use the disk image uninstaller. The same (terse) advice is given in the official [Call Recorder FAQ](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/callrecorder/faq.html).

However, I don't know how to find Call Recorder's disk image uninstaller. A search in Finder across my whole computer for "Call Recorder" finds nothing, and it isn't in my Applications directory either.

How can I get rid of this software? It has now [killed Skype completely](http://community.skype.com/t5/Mac/Skype-continually-crashes-upon-opening/td-p/923254/page/2) - unless I can uninstall it I can't use Skype at all.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out... you have to re-download Call Recorder's installer, then run it and choose the 'Uninstall' option. Very tedious, and poor documentation from Call Recorder.

Answer (score 0):

for osx : You can alternatively from future  please use [app zapper](http://appzapper.com/) and [app cleaner](http://www.reggieashworth.com/) which are alternatives for the windows and uninstall the dependency files for that app.

ps: overlooked the osx tag